# Copy Each '.txt' File into respective date folder Based on Date in Filename using data factory

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

``
I have to copy files from source folder to target folder both are in the same storage account(ADL). The files in the source folder are of in .txt format and have date appended in the file name,
eg: RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
and
RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
(20221201 and 20221202 is date in file name , date format: yyyymmdd)

I have to create a pipeline that will sort and store files in the folders in ADL's in this hierarchy
ex: adl/2022/12/01/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
adl/2022/12/02/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt

even if we have multiple files on same date in file name based on that date in file name it has to create year(YYYY) folder and in year(YYYY) folder it should create month(MM) folder and in month(MM) folder it should create date(DD) folder like above example. Each File should copy into respective yyyy and respective mm and respective date folder.

```
What I have done:
In Get Metadata -  Given argument to extract **childitems**

For each activity that contains a Copy activity. 
 In Copy activity source wildcard path is given as *.txt
for sink took concat expression using split and substring functions
Please check the screenshots of all activities and expressions
but this pipeline is creating the folders based on date in file name (like adl/2022/12/01) 
but problem is it was copying all files into all date(DD) folders 
(like adl/2022/12/01/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
                     RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
      
      adl/2022/12/02/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
                     RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt)



1.[GET META to extract child items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVYgZ.png)
2.[Giving GET META output to FOREACH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbo30.png)
3.[Inside FOREACH using COPY ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5LK5.png)
4.[Source Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyzuC.png)
5.[Sink Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiYYm.png) Expression used in Data Set in Folder Path '@concat('adl','/'dataset().FolderName)
6.[Took parameter for Sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QihZR.png) 
7.[Sink in copy activity ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OzT5.png)
Expression used in sink for dynamic folders using split and substring function
@concat(substring(split(item().name,'.')[3],0,4),'/',
        substring(split(item().name,'.')[3],4,2),'/',
        substring(split(item().name,'.')[3],6,2)
       )


**OUTPUT for this pipeline**

adl/2022/12/01/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
               RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
      
adl/2022/12/02/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
               RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt


**Required Output is**

adl/2022/12/01/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221201.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt
      
adl/2022/12/02/RAINBOW.IND.EXPORT.20221202.WIFI.NETWORK.SCHOOL.txt

(i.e each file should copy to respective date folders only even if we have multiple files in same date, they should copy to date folders based on date in file name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got same result when I followed the steps that you have given.

[image]

Copy activity did like this because, in source or sink you did not gave `@item().name`(**file name for that particular iteration**) and you have given ***.txt** in the wildcard path of source in copy activity.

It means **for every iteration(for every file name)** it copies all .txt files from source into that particular target folder(same happened for you).

To avoid this,

1. **Give `@item().name` in source wild card file name**

[image]

It means we are giving only one that iteration file name in the source for the copy.

**(OR)**

2. Keep the wildcard file name in source as it is(`*.txt`) and create a sink dataset parameter for file name.

[image]

and give `@item().name` to it in copy activity sink.

[image]

You can do any of the above and if you want you can do both at a time. I have checked all the 3 scenarios like

> 1.`@item().name` in wild card sink file name.
> 2. `@item().name` in dataset file name by keeping wildcard path same.
> 3. combining both 1 and 2(`@item().name` in wild card file name and in sink dataset parameter).

All are working fine and giving desired result.

[image]